# How do I feed Skype a prerecorded video?

Tags: skype

I would like to feed Skype (2.2.0.35) with a pre-recorded video. Anyone has done this? Please share your experience.

I've compiled gstfakevideo, but it fails like this:

```
alexk@z2:~/gstfakevideo$ gstfakevideo 
gst.c create_pipeline (155): pipeline created
gst.c create_pipeline (159): pipeline linked
gst.c shim_ioctl (201): request=80685600 nr 0
gst.c shim_ioctl (296): result=-1 error=515 Неизвестная ошибка 515
```

Comment: If you want a super simple way to do this just use the 'screen sharing' built in to Skype. Activate it during a call by clicking the blue camera button below the video, choose 'Share your screen -> Share selection'. Resize the red selection box over your video, start screen sharing, and play it. It works best for occasional use.

Comment: I'll try that.  It sure seems smart. +1

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

You can use the [**Webcam Studio**](http://www.ws4gl.org/), which will allow you to use pre-recorded media, such as images, audio/video, etc. as a source to create a virtual "bridge" between your live streams (webcam, digital cameras/players, etc.) and other media.

Unfortunately I don't have who to call in order to perform a test right now but I have used this for both Skype and Web Based Services like ***Ubiqq*** (http://www.ubiqq.com) and ***Ustream.TV*** (http://www.ustream.tv/) As shown in the provided screenshots.

[image]

*On this screenshot you can see Skype recognizing `Webcam studio Video Device (/dev/video0)` as a source, somehow the "Test" button won't work (at least on my system) but it works when on a call.*

[image]

*This screenshot shows the usage of the Virtual Video Device from WebcamStudio on ubiqq. Which is a flash/web based video conferencing system.*

Give this a try. Webcam Studio will allow you to choose both live and pre-recorded media, and enrich it with effects which includes animations, text, and further more.

I hope this help you and if so, enjoy!

Good luck!

Comment: This is very nice, but it seems that webcamstudio doesn't work with latest skype version.

Comment: 2.2.0.35-0natty1