# Use image as video stream?

Tags: video, video-streaming

I want to use an image as a video stream source in flashplayer, for websites like ustream. Preferably something light on memory/cpu.

From what I've read, xawtv might be able to create a fake vloopback source from a picture?

Thoughts on how to accomplish this?

*PS.
I know about ws4l, but it is VERY resource heavy for this simple purpose.*

Comment: Do you want to make a movie from image files like jpeg?

Answer (score 1):

***Parts of this answer come from: [How do I feed Skype a prerecorded video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64700/how-do-i-feed-skype-a-prerecorded-video)***

Sure you can.

You can use the [**Webcam Studio**](http://www.ws4gl.org/), which will allow you to use pre-recorded media, such as images, audio/video, etc. as a source to create a virtual "bridge" between your live streams (webcam, digital cameras/players, etc.) and other media.

I have used this for both Skype and Flash/Web Based Services like ***Ubiqq*** (http://www.ubiqq.com) and ***Ustream.TV*** (http://www.ustream.tv/) As shown in the provided screenshots.

[image: screenshot]

*This screenshot shows the usage of the Virtual Video Device from WebcamStudio on ubiqq. Which is a flash/web based video conferencing system.*

Webcam Studio will allow you to choose both live and pre-recorded media, and enrich it with effects which includes animations, text, and further more.

Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I put in the description that I am already aware of ws4l. This is not a light resource solution.